# Can't save save/export and load a keras model that uses eager execution

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I'm following the RNN text-generation tutorial with eager execution pretty much line for line. I've trained the model with my own data set and have saved a low loss checkpoint. I'm able to load the weights and generate text but I want to export/save the model so that I can learn how to deploy one using flask. However I can't figure out how. The version I'm using is '1.14.0-rc1'.

The tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/sequences/text_generation

I have been able to save the model as an HDF5 file but I cannot load it. I've also disabled eager execution but that causes problems with running the code later on. I have tried the following and a few more snippets but those led to nothing as well:

```
new_model = keras.models.load_model("/content/gdrive/My Drive/ColabNotebooks/ckpt4/my_model.h5")
```

How ever I get

`RuntimeError: tf.placeholder() is not compatible with eager execution.`

Lastly I found this in another post and tried it as well but was met with another error:

`tf.saved_model.save(model, "/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/ckpt4/my_model.h5")`

error:

`AssertionError: Tried to export a function which references untracked object Tensor("StatefulPartitionedCall/args_2:0", shape=(), dtype=resource).TensorFlow objects (e.g. tf.Variable) captured by functions must be tracked by assigning them to an attribute of a tracked object or assigned to an attribute of the main object directly.`